# boost::interprocess message queue timed_receive() internal procedure

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue

im currently using the *timed_receive()* method from the *boost::interprocess* library for receiving data. Since the timing of the received messages will vary I used this method over the *receive()* method.

```
msgque->timed_receive((void*) &message,sizeof(int),recvd_size,priority,
            boost::posix_time::ptime(microsec_clock::universal_time()) + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(300))
```

**Question:**
How does this method know a message is present in the buffer? Is it a polling mechanism or is there a more complex mechanism implemented?
I read the documentation and couldnt find any details and the source code wasnt informative either.

Thanks already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't need to document how it works, because that's an implementation detail. You ideally do not need to know, which is why you use a library in the first place.

You can expect the library to implement it in terms of more primitive library building blocks:

- shared_memory_object + mapped_region
- [mutex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes), + [condition](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.conditions)

That implies that the condition gets signaled by another process.

However it's also possible that something more advanced / specialized is used on a given platform (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/how-is-a-message-queue-implemented-in-the-linux-kernel).

A quick scan of the source code confirms a straight-forward implementation on first principles using the building blocks from the library:

```
//Mutex to protect data structures
interprocess_mutex         m_mutex;
//Condition block receivers when there are no messages
interprocess_condition     m_cond_recv;
//Condition block senders when the queue is full
interprocess_condition     m_cond_send;
#if defined(BOOST_INTERPROCESS_MSG_QUEUE_CIRCULAR_INDEX)
//Current start offset in the circular index
size_type                  m_cur_first_msg;
size_type                  m_blocked_senders;
size_type                  m_blocked_receivers;
#endif
```

There's **extensive** inline documentation. I suggest you read through it if you want to know more.

Comment: [Fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63144272/revisions) a formatting mishap. Sorry about that.