# Boost Message Queue with Posix Message Queue

Tags: boost, posix, ipc

I have IPC mechanism written using boost interprocess message queue in Process A. This basically receives and sends data with Process A. The reason for using boost message queue is for considering windows and linux compatibility.

But Process B is a linux only version which uses posix message queue implementation. Is there any compatibility issue with this scenario ? which is Process A open the boost message queue and waiting for Process B to send data using posix message queue if they using the same queue name ?

Answer (score 1):

Boost Interprocesses message queue (`message_queue`) does NOT use Posix message queues, at all. There is no compatibility with other programs that do not use Boost Interprocess.

See here for analysis: [boost::interprocess message queue timed_receive() internal procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135687/boostinterprocess-message-queue-timed-receive-internal-procedure/63144272#63144272)